# Refrescar pagina React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Como puedo refrescar una página en React, lo he intentado con `reload` pero se queda guardado el `state` de antes.

```
export default class Cabecera extends Component {
        reload = () => {
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
        render() {
        return (

                <button onClick={this.reload} type="button">RECARGAR</button>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Al parecer si hago un history push antes y despues refresco si que me elimina el state.

```
this.props.history.push(this.props.match.url)
window.location.reload(true);
```

¿Por que pasa esto?

Comment: El `state` es cargado en memoria. Si refrescas el documento se liberará lo que hay en ella, incluído la última versión del `state`.

Comment: @gugadev En mi caso no pasa eso, tengo que ir a otro link y volver para que se elimine el state.

Comment: El state no es persistente; cualquier refresh significa un nuevo mount de la aplicación. Es rarísimo que tu state sea guardado aún luego de recargar. La única forma de lograr eso es que uses algún middleware como [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).

Comment: @gugadev Creo que se guarda en el history, estoy utilizando React router, alomejor es culpa de eso

Comment: Es lo más probable :)

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay otras alternativas

```js
window.location.href = window.location.href;
// or
window.location.replace('');
```